# Quip component isn't able to see template

Tags: lightning, quip

Let's say we have Quip Document Component in Account record page. I set up `Different templates for different record` and appropriate fields values. I'm sure that `Template URL` is correct and my user have an access to document. But i'm not able to create new doc from template in UI (there is no any option). What did I miss?[image]

Comment: what do they see in the component?

Comment: Absolutely nothing except `Document` icon. I updated question

Comment: They don't get presented with the "connect to quip" button or has that already been done? There's the [setup](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.anywhere_turn_on.htm&type=5) and then permission sets as well that need to be assigned. I know you selected different templates, but you can copy one of your urls in that record's custom field and test it's valid if you select `one template for each record` per this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_quip_embed_doc_component.htm&type=5). That'll help make sure the template URL is at least all set.